# Mono For Android Tutorial: Grid View how is it iterating through each thumbnail

Tags: android, mono

I am going through this tutorial:
http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/User_Interface/grid_view

I am an experienced programmer but newer to Android so that is probably the issue.

I understand what is happening but I do not see/understand how the GetView() in the ImageAdapter is being called for each individual resource in thumbs[].

I debugged and stepped through the code but still do not see what/how it is calling the GetView() function to generate a view for each thumb and how it is incrementing the count/position counter that calls GetView().

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GridView/ListView/ExpandableListView/Gallery classes in Android provide important optimizations that allow you to display long lists or grids of content without drawing the entire list at the same time.

These AdapterView classes have an underlying adapter that provides the AdapterView with a view for any given cell.  So even though a ListView may contain 100 items, if only 6 items are visible in the view at a time, then the AdapterView may only draw ~8 items.

The getView() method in your Adapter will be called by the AdapterView when the user scrolls to the position of that item in the AdapterView.  The count should not be being incremented, unless the number of "cells" you intend to be visible in the AdapterView is increasing.

Generally in your implementation of getView(), you will want to recycle the existing view if possible and only update the text/images with the data from your model.

Comment: So the adapater is called automatically and since we are using "override View GetView" override I am assuming the GetView is a built in function of the Adapter.  So it just "knows" to display only what fits on the screen. So there is no actual CALL to the adapter.                                                                   So now it fits 6-8 images on a screen at the time using the height/width it is at now, so the adapter is called 8 times to display them.  If I updated the height/width to be larger and only 4 fit on the screen it would only call the adapter 4 times?

Comment: So does each image that is generated in the grid view have its own object instantionated with it?  Meaning can I add varaibles to teh adapter class and when I click on the image it now returns the position, but if I add variables to the adapter and set them when the adapter calls/generates the images can I then access those variables as well?   Or do I have to have another object that just ties to the position in the adapter?

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track.  If there were 4 objects visible, then yes, getView() in the Adapter would be called at least 4 times.  You can declare variables and reference them in getView - usually you will have a list from which the count is derived, and that you can use to retrieve an object with the data for the current item in the list/grid.  See this example of an Adapter extending BaseAdapter: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/